# Get data from restsharp json

Tags: asp.net, json

Need help on how to get data from an restsharp response

The json i get in response looks like this
"{"requestId":"144x25","responseId":"2a7407d8-700e-4535-8868-a9599062eb54","allowedItemIds":["100331976","101024753"]}"

The alloweditemsids could be up to 15000
I need to get the responseID and AllowedItemsIDs

I have tried with both of this to convert (not at the same time)

```
var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);
dynamic data = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
```

But how to get the alloweditesids from data

Cheers
Niclas